# zend 3 pdoexception sqlite table not found but exists

Tags: sqlite, pdo, zend-framework3

I am working with zend framework 3 skeleton project.
I receive sqlite pdoexception :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: posts

table most definitely exists, I ran a php file and viewed all its record in command prompt, code is ok too, when I use an already created table instead of table posts, it works. What could be wrong?

Comment: Error in your (secret) code? Wrong database file? How should anybody know without more information?

Comment: When I use an already created table in the same database file, it works, so code could not be wrong. Tables are all in the same database file so path could not be wrong too. Suppose using another driver but Pdo, any opinon?

Comment: You aren't posting enough information to specify the problem. How are you connecting to the DB? tablegateways/ORM/plain PDO

Comment: It is PDO driver . As I said before , when I use another table which is already created , I have no problem. So pdo works. This problem occurs only when I use a newly created table.